# Is there a way to get ride off the thickness ContentDialog in web assembly?

Tags: uno-platform

I am using the ContentDialog as modal in my app and I need to get rid of the thickness in it, so I don't get any padding in it. Done it in UWP by overriding the style of the element, since that doesn't work in a WASM is there another way of doing this?

```
 <ContentDialog.Resources>        
    <Thickness x:Key="ContentDialogPadding">0,0,0,0</Thickness>
    <x:Double x:Key="ContentDialogMaxWidth">972</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="ContentDialogMaxHeight">928</x:Double>
```

**Wanted result(UWP):**[image]

**Result I got(WASM):**[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Uno Platform doesn't support overriding individual framework resources this way, this is slated for a [future Uno release](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/pull/1766).

For now, the only way to do this with Uno is to override the entire `ContentDialog` style:

1. Copy the default [ContentDialog style](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/master/src/Uno.UI/UI/Xaml/Controls/ContentDialog/ContentDialog.xaml) into your app, and include it in `Application.Resources.MergedDictionaries`.
2. Modify the `ContentDialogPadding` property within that style.